# Can the C++ API be used to develop scopes for Unity 7?

Tags: unity, application-development, unity-dash, scopes

I want to develop a Unity 7 scope for Ubuntu 14.04. I've found a nice introduction [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/scopes/sdk-14.04/index/), but unity-scope-tool depends on Unity 8 which I don't won't to install. As I can see, most of the other scopes are written in Vala or Python.

Can I use [C++ api](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/scopes/sdk-14.04/) to develop scopes for Unity 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the question at the #ubuntu-unity IRC channel and it looks like the new C++ API is only available for the Unity8 infrastructure. So, the answer is NO.

Answer (score -1):

I honestly see no issue.  Your using C++ to develop code for an OS.  As long as you know what your doing, you should be able to compile with minimal effort and issue.

Comment: It not a problem to compile a sample scope based on a new Unity8 API. I just can't figure out how to get it working with Unity7 Dash.